# Spring Boot Actuator - Endpoint sensitivity vs security enablement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've been reading up on the spring boot actuator and I'm having a hard time distinguishing between two application.properties settings

`endpoints.sensitive` vs `management.security.enabled`

I want to customize the access rules of the actuator endpoints.  I can control all [actuator endpoint sensitivity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints) using the `endpoints.sensitive` property.  My understanding is that a sensitive endpoint will require authorization. I can also [change the accessibility](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints) of the endpoints via the `management.security.enabled` property.

What's the distinction between the sensitivity controls and the security enablement?

Comment: Note to future readers: the option "sensitive" seems to be from Spring 1.x ([see this docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints)), and the concept has changed in Spring 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of actuator endpoints "sensitive" means something like 'may emit sensitive information' so there is an implied need for authentication. So if you set `endpoints.sensitive=true` then `management.security.enabled` will be true too. Conversely, if you set `management.security.enabled=false` then your endpoints are implicitly non-sensitive.

Springs docs provide a neat table which outlines the possible choices:

```
management.security.enabled | endpoints.health.sensitive |Unauthenticated |Authenticated (with right role)
--------------------------- | -------------------------- |--------------- |--------------------------------
false                       | *                          | Full content   | Full content
true                        | false                      | Status only    | Full content
true                        | true                       | No content     | Full content
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and feedback.  I'm still a little confused, are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: I don't think they are mutually exclusive. If you set `endpoints.sensitive=true` then you are implicitly setting `management.security.enabled=true` since 'management security' is the _means by which_ endpoint security is provided.

Comment: Gotcha, and the table you provided sheds some light on it as well.  It's not just a boolean state since there can be partial data exposure (e.g. health endpoint).

Comment: Yep, `endpoints.sensitive` can actually be `endpoints.X.sensitive` where `X` is an endpoint name such as health, info etc.